# STTwitter Collect people i mention and those who mention me

Tags: twitter, sttwitter

using STTwitter Library I'm planing to go back in time and Collect as much as i can the Ids of those people who mention me and i mention them as well and store them within the app itself .

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get mentions of yourself in other's tweets, use [this method](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/blob/master/STTwitter/STTwitterAPI.h#L151).

To get mentions of others in your own tweets, use [this one](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/blob/master/STTwitter/STTwitterAPI.h#L177) and look at tweet entities.

You may have to play with the `count` value, and also call the methods again while setting `maxID` to the lowest ID you've always have.

Let me know if it doesn't fulfill your needs.